# Storing top level JSON key for use after reshaping JSON with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm playing around with some [MTGJSON](https://mtgjson.com/downloads/all-files/) data and I'm trying to convert data from a file called AllPrintings.json that looks like:

```
{
  "10E": {
    "cards": [
      {
        "name": "Abundance",
        "prices": {
          "paper": {
            "2020-06-11": 1.4
          },
          "paperFoil": {
            "2020-06-11": 31.12
          }
        },
        "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441442f"
      },
      {
        "name": "Academy Researchers",
        "prices": {
          "paper": {
            "2020-06-11": 0.36
          },
          "paperFoil": {
            "2020-06-11": 1.22
          }
        },
        "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcaf9815"
      }
    ]
  },
  "BFZ": {
    "cards": [
      {
        "name": "Adverse Conditions",
        "prices": {
          "paper": {
            "2020-06-11": 0.23
          },
          "paperFoil": {
            "2020-06-11": 1.86
          }
        },
        "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441123"
      },
      {
        "name": "Akoum Firebird",
        "prices": {
          "paper": {
            "2020-06-11": 0.51
          },
          "paperFoil": {
            "2020-06-11": 3.85
          }
        },
        "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcafad567"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Into:

```
{
  {
    "name": "Abundance",
    "price": 1.4,
    "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441442f",
    "set": "10E"
  },
  {
    "name": "Academy Researchers",
    "price": 0.36,
    "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcaf9815",
    "set": "10E"
  },
  {
    "name": "Adverse Conditions",
    "price": 0.23,
    "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441123",
    "set": "BFZ"
  },
  {
    "name": "Akoum Firebird",
    "price": 0.51,
    "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcafad567",
    "set": "BFZ"
  },
}
```

I'm able to get everything except the set by running

```
cat AllPrintings.json | jq '[.[] | .cards | .[] |  {uuid: .uuid, name: .name, price: .prices.paper | .[]? }]'
```

which returns

```
{
  {
    "name": "Abundance",
    "price": 1.4,
    "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441442f",
  },
  {
    "name": "Academy Researchers",
    "price": 0.36,
    "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcaf9815",
  },
  {
    "name": "Adverse Conditions",
    "price": 0.23,
    "uuid": "1669af17-d287-5094-b005-4b143441123",
  },
  {
    "name": "Akoum Firebird",
    "price": 0.51,
    "uuid": "047d5499-a21c-5f5c-9679-1599fcafad567",
  },
}
```

I've tried storing the top level keys as $k and can get an array of the keys in a separate command but I'm unable to keep iterating over the original data afterwards. I've tried the comma separator but I get errors or the query hangs. For instance

```
cat AllPrintings.json | jq ‘. | keys as $k, [.[] | .cards | .[] |  {uuid: .uuid, name: .name, price: .prices.paper, key: $k | .[]? }]'
```

I've search here and have read through the jq documentation but I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for. I'm also likely overthinking this or missing an obvious solution. Any help would be appreciated. If this is a duplicate question please link me to the original and I'll delete my post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. The missing part is `to_entries`, which converts an object into `{key, value}` pairs:

```
to_entries | map(.key as $set | .value.cards[] | {uuid, name, price: .prices.paper | .[]?, set: $set })
```

Comment: I don't immediately understand how this works but it does! I'll go back to the documentation to better understand to_entires and how map works in jq. Thank you.

Comment: Added wrinkle. I've updated my example code to include a paper price and a paperFoil price. When using `to_entries | map(.key as $set | .value.cards[] | {uuid, name, price: .prices.paper, foilPrice: .prices.paperFoil | .[]?, set: $set })` one price has only the number as the value (which is what I want) but the other has the date/value object as it's value. It appears to be dependent on which I reference first. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: You need to apply the `.[]?` transformation to both keys: `{..., price: .prices.paper | .[]?, foilPrice: .prices.paperFoil | .[]?, ...}`

Comment: That makes senses. I missed that the result was being piped into the array transformation. Thank you again.